# Image Slider (or jquery plugin) which flashes next and previous images

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I searched all the web and couldn't find a made slideshow (preferably a jquery plugin) to show images in a slideshow in a certain way: I want to have the "focused" image and flash a part of the previous and next images at the left and right of it. I will thank if anyone can help me with my search.
Thanks!!

Comment: please make review for the answer

Comment: Come on Mateo I gave this to you from my jquery plugin database. Please select the answer if they are helpful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the links
http://www.mopstudio.jp/mopSlider2demo.html
http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials
http://www.themeflash.com/30-stunning-jquery-slider-plugins-and-tutorials-to-boost-your-work/
http://wowslider.com/automatic-jquery-slider-noir-squares-demo.html
http://www.megalomanie.cz/jquery-blended/
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/667/jQuery-Countdown-Image-Slider-Plugin
http://www.hugoandcat.com/DualSlider/index.html
http://visionwidget.com/inspiration/web/453-javascript-flash-photo-gallery.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. The exact thing I need is a plugin as http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/ but without the resize, much simpler! I tried to change the code of that plugin but couldn't make it, if someone knows a plugin similar to moving boxes I will thank him!